# Problema con sobrecarga de constructores java

Tags: java, constructor, sobrecarga

¿por que cuando realizo una sobrecarga de constructores no me inicializa la variable?
me explico con un ejemplo corto:

```
1Clase:
2Clase a = new 2Clase("Alto");
```

inicializo la segunda clase y le paso el argumento

```
2Clase:

String valor1;

public SegundaClase(String valor){
this.valor1 = valor;
}

System.out.println(valor1); = "Alto"
```

Aquí todo normal, el System.out... devuelve el argumento dado en la primera clase "Alto", el problema aparece cuando realizo una sobre carga de constructores por ejemplo: si cambio el código de la segunda clase por el siguiente el System.out... deja de devolverme el argumento "Alto" y pasa a devolverme "Null":

```
2Clase:

String valor1;

public 2Clase(){}

public 2Clase(String valor){
this.valor1 = valor;
}

System.out.println(valor1); "Null"
```

Comment: ¿Y por qué, según tú, debería mostrar `Alto` en el segundo caso?

Comment: Hola Jose, bienvenido, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, y evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 0):

Como verás en el siguiente ejemplo, la sobrecarga del constructor, no ocasiona ningún problema... si se usa "bien".

```
public class Clase1 {  
    String valor1;
    
    public Clase1( String valor ) { 
        this.valor1 = valor; 
    }

    public getValor() {
       return valor1;
    }
}

public class Clase2 {
    String valor1;
    
    public Clase2() { }
    
    public Clase2( String valor ) { 
        this.valor1 = valor; 
    }

    public getValor() {
       return valor1;
    }
}

public class Prueba {
    Clase1 a1 = new Clase1("Alto");   
    Clase2 a2 = new Clase2("Alto");    
    Clase2 a3 = new Clase2();   
    public static void main( String[] arg ) {
        System.out.println( a1.getValor() ); // imprime "Alto"  
        System.out.println( a2.getValor() ); // imprime "Alto"  
        System.out.println( a3.getValor() ); // imprime "Null"
    }
}
```

Si intentas lo siguiente:

```
Clase1 a4 = new Clase1();
```

te arroja un error porque **Clase1**, no tiene un constructor vacio.